# Python - Match elements from different list with irregular length to new list

Tags: python

Hey this may be simple but I'm stuck... i have 3 different lists that i want to match up in a certain way but i can´t seam to get it right. The `RDBID` is a index to separate the strings form each other `(ex 1636 19 02 2F has RDBID 1)` `byte` is the nr in which order the string has `(ex 1636=0 19=1 02=2 2F=3)` and `hex` is the string that i have to sort from. My problem is that some `hex` strings are longer then others so i don´t get the right output, so i need in some way count `byte` to then how many elements i should take from `hex` and at the same time index every byte+hex with RDBID..

i have tried making separate `for loop` for each list and then appended everything to a new list, did not work... tried making 3 `nested loop` in the same way but then every value got printed on separate lines... tried searching for element patterns but did not work either... i´m completely stuck

```
RDBID = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
byte = (0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
hex = ('1636', '19', '02', '2F', '1637', '19', '02', '2F', '1631', '19', '02', '2F', '1637', '19', '04', '0A', '1B', '47', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '06', '07', '68', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '06', '0A', '82', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '0A', '78', '56', 'FF','1637', '19', '04', '0A', '78', '56', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '0A', '1B', '08', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '0A', '1B', '81', 'FF')

how i could like it to get printed/stored in a new_list:
        (1,0,1636)
        (1,1,19)  
        (1,2,02)
        (1,3,27)
        (2,0,1637)
        (2,1,19)
        (2,2,02)
        (2,3,2F)
        (3,0,1631)
        (3,1,19)
        (3,2,02)
        (3,3,2F)
        (4,1,1637)
        (4,2,18)
        (4,3,04)
        (4,4,0A)
        (4,5,1B)
        (4,6,47)
        (4,7,FF)
         .....
```

why i want to store in in that way is because i will write it over to my Access Sql server later
so now i´m asking for some help, Thanks

Comment: You claim to have written code (however incorrect) for this; where is it?

Comment: is has been rewritten and over written several times now, so ist just chaos, that´s why i´m asking for new help @ScottHunter

Comment: Can you please review your expected output? I believe `(1,3,27)` should be `(1,3,2F)` and then I think for `(4,1,1637)` onwards the `byte` parameter should be one digit less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below code you can get what you expect:

```
RDBID = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
byte = (0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
hex = ('1636', '19', '02', '2F', '1637', '19', '02', '2F', '1631', '19', '02', '2F', '1637', '19', '04', '0A', '1B', '47', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '06', '07', '68', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '06', '0A', '82', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '0A', '78', '56', 'FF','1637', '19', '04', '0A', '78', '56', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '0A', '1B', '08', 'FF', '1637', '19', '04', '0A', '1B', '81', 'FF')

zipByteHex = zip(byte,hex)

result = list()
i = -1
for bh in zipByteHex:
    if bh[0]==0:
        i+=1
    result.append((RDBID[i],)+bh)
```

And result would be as follows:

```
>>> result
[(1, 0, '1636'),
 (1, 1, '19'),
 (1, 2, '02'),
 (1, 3, '2F'),
 (2, 0, '1637'),
 (2, 1, '19'),
 (2, 2, '02'),
 (2, 3, '2F'),
 (3, 0, '1631'),
 (3, 1, '19'),
 (3, 2, '02'),
 (3, 3, '2F'),
 (4, 0, '1637'),
 (4, 1, '19'),
 (4, 2, '04'),
 (4, 3, '0A'),
 (4, 4, '1B'),
 (4, 5, '47'),
 (4, 6, 'FF'),
 (5, 0, '1637'),
 (5, 1, '19'),
 (5, 2, '04'),
 (5, 3, '06'),
 (5, 4, '07'),
 (5, 5, '68'),
 (5, 6, 'FF'),
 (6, 0, '1637'),
 (6, 1, '19'),
 (6, 2, '04'),
 (6, 3, '06'),
 (6, 4, '0A'),
 (6, 5, '82'),
 (6, 6, 'FF'),
 (7, 0, '1637'),
 (7, 1, '19'),
 (7, 2, '04'),
 (7, 3, '0A'),
 (7, 4, '78'),
 (7, 5, '56'),
 (7, 6, 'FF'),
 (8, 0, '1637'),
 (8, 1, '19'),
 (8, 2, '04'),
 (8, 3, '0A'),
 (8, 4, '78'),
 (8, 5, '56'),
 (8, 6, 'FF'),
 (9, 0, '1637'),
 (9, 1, '19'),
 (9, 2, '04'),
 (9, 3, '0A'),
 (9, 4, '1B'),
 (9, 5, '08'),
 (9, 6, 'FF'),
 (10, 0, '1637'),
 (10, 1, '19'),
 (10, 2, '04'),
 (10, 3, '0A'),
 (10, 4, '1B'),
 (10, 5, '81'),
 (10, 6, 'FF')]
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function does some work which avoids you to do another extra loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from what little information you've given that only the `hex` variable has any useful data in it.  So, why not something like this?

```
RDBID = 1
_byte = 0
for s in hex:
    print (RDBID, _byte, s)
    if byte >= 3:
        byte = 0
        RDBID += 1
    else:
        byte += 1
```

Comment: Output of this code does not match what @sesar expects.